# XML Parser Using Restkit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    RKClient *client = [[RKClient alloc] initWithBaseURLString:wwww.example.org];
    [RKClient setSharedClient:client];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] get:\components.xml delegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response{  
    NSLog(@"response %@",response.bodyAsString);
}
```

I am  using Xml parsing from restkit. But the response show null. Anyone know the xml parser using restkit , help me.

Comment: Any special reason to use 'RKClient' or you're using it just for normal XML parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is link you may Refer

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/
 https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

Comment: I implement the restkit functions but , i dont know the how to parse the xml elements , and the json parsing is working fine. can anyone help me !!!!